# How do I clear only part of a depth/stencil view?

Tags: directx, directx-11, direct3d, direct3d11

If I want to clear an entire depth/stencil view in Direct3D 11, I can easily call [`ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearDepthStencilView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476387(v=vs.85).aspx).

Direct3D 11.1 adds support for clearing rectangular portions of *render target* views using [`ID3D11DeviceContext1::ClearView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404601(v=vs.85).aspx).

But I see no way to clear only a portion of a depth/stencil view in Direct3D 11, short of rendering a quad over the desired area? This seems like an odd regression from Direct3D 9, where this was trivially easy. Am I missing something, or is this really not supported?

Comment: You should add details on why you need such a thing, because partial clear of surfaces come at a big price in performance for latter operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function that can clear only a part of depth/stencil view.
This is my way to solve the problem:

1. make a texture. Set Alpha of the part to clear to 1,and other part to 0.
2. open `AlphaTest`, only the pixel whose alpha is 1.
3. open `AlphaBlend`,set `BlendOP` to `Add`,set `SrcBlend` factor to 0,set `DestBlend` factor to 1.
4. set `StencilTest` and `DepthTest` to `Always`, set `StencilRef` to the value you want to clear.
5. use orthogonal projection matrix.
6. draw a rectangle that just covers the screen( z-coordinate/(ZFar-ZNear) will convert to depth),and paste the texture on it.

Comment: Yeah, I figured something like this was necessary. I was really hoping to avoid having to set and then restore all that state just to do a clear operation. Thanks.

Comment: This is usually bad practice to clear only a portion of a depth buffer and even color buffer. Doing so will defeat all the precious GPUs optimisation like Hi-Z. And it is even worse if you involve the stencil just for a clear. GPUs have fast clear features and if you do not read the depth buffer, there is no way to beat that. What is your original problem ? And even if you need a quad clear, please does not involve textures or stencil, you can just draw a quad to cover the region with the proper depth to write the value.

Comment: @galop1n I'm porting an existing game engine from D3D9 to D3D11. The engine supports clearing rectangular sub-regions of both color and depth/stencil buffers, so I need to emulate that in D3D11. And no, I can't remove that feature from the engine because lots of games depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent reason at removing the partial clears in the API. First, it is always possible to emulate them by drawing quads with proper render states, and second, all GPUs have fast clear and resolve hardware. Using them in the intend logic greatly improve performance of the rendering.

With the DX11 clear API, it is possible to use the fast clear and the latter GPU optimisation. A depth buffer fast clear also prepare for an early depth test ( prior to pixel shading, because yes, the real depth test is post pixel shading ), and some bandwidth optimisation on access to the depth buffer will rendering. If you clear with a quad, you lost all that and draw cost will rise.